# Code First : Unable to create 1 to many relationship. Creates 0...1 to many instead

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first

Customer

```
public class Customer
{
    public Customer()
    {
        Addresses = new List<Address>();
        Reviews = new List<Review>();
        Products = new List<Product>();
    }
    [Key]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public Address DefaultAddress { get; set; }
    public int DefaultAddressId { get; set; }
    public List<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
    public List<Review> Reviews { get; set; }
    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

Product

```
public class Product
{
    public Product()
    {
        Reviews = new List < Review >();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }  
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Specification { get; set; }
    public List<Review> Reviews { get; set; }
    public List<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
}
```

Review

```
public class Review
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public int Stars { get; set; }
    [Required] 
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string CustomerId { get; set; }
}
```

}

Generated model

[image]

I want the relationship between Review and Customer to 1 to many not 0..1 to many. Each review must belong to one customer.  I don't understand how the relationship is mapped properly for Review - Product but not for the customer.

Comment: Maybe because the key for customer is a string, which is nullable? I would always use a non-nullable type for a key.

Comment: @oerkelens in this scenario customerId is the email since it's unique for each customer. It has to be a string.

Comment: never, i repeat never use a string as the PK.  it will end in tears!  sure make a unique constraint for email but use a proper type like int, guid.

Comment: The email has to be a string. The technical unique key does NEVER have to be a string. It's often considered bad practice to even assign a functional meaning to a primary key.

Comment: Changing id of customer table to int fixed it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

i only used `Customer` and `Review` models since those are the once you wanted an answer.
Following is the your model classes should be.

```
public class Customer
{
    public Customer()
    {
        Reviews = new HashSet<Review>();
    }

    [Key]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Review> Reviews { get; set; }

}

public class Review
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public int Stars { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string CustomerId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CustomerId")]
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

this way you can have customers Review collection and cast it in to a list if you want.use `Include()` method in your linq query to lazy load the customers review collection.
for an example:

```
var customer = dbContext.Customer.Include("Reviews").where(x => x.Email == "john@gmail.com").FirstOrDefault();
```